# Revealing and hiding a playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way of writing this? I feel like there's a lot of lines for such a small thing.  Can it be optimized?

```
$j('#hideShowBtn').toggle(function() {
     $j('.playlist-bar-tray').slideUp();
     $j(this).attr("title","Show Playlist");         
     $j(this).children("div").html('Show Playlist');
     $j(this).children("span").html('&#9660;');
 }, function() {
     $j('.playlist-bar-tray').slideDown();
     $j(this).attr("title","Hide Playlist");
     $j(this).children("div").html('Hide Playlist');
     $j(this).children("span").html('&#9650;');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it can be written *differently* with less repetition, but it's readable as it is. There are 4 things that need to happen when the toggling occurs; your code does exactly that. It's the simplest way to write it, really.

My only real suggestion would be to cache `$j(this)` in a variable to avoid recreating it.

Regardless, here's a funky rewrite, just for the sake of it

```
function toggle(hiding) {
  var title   = (hiding ? "Show Playlist" : "Hide Playlist"),
      symbol  = (hiding ? "&#9960"        : "&#9650"),
      method  = (hiding ? "slideUp"       : "slideDown");

  return function () {
    var element = $j(this);
    element.attr("title", title).children("div").html(title);
    element.children("span").html(symbol);
    $j(".playlist-bar-tray")[method]();
  };
}

$j('#hideShowBtn').toggle( toggle(true), toggle(false) );
```

Comment: I actually really like that solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lelly Glad you found it useful. But do check out ZeroOne's answer too, and read its comments. There's a lot to gain by keeping the content in the markup, and only the behavior in the JS

Answer (score 7):

How about "cheating" a bit by creating two copies of those elements whose values should change and then just alternate between which element to show. Something like this:

```
<div class="toggleable">
    <span>&#9660;</span> Show playlist
</div>
<div class="toggleable" style="display: none;">
    <span>&#9650;</span> Hide playlist
</div>
```

And then somewhere in your JavaScript you call the [.toggle() function from the jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/toggle/):

```
$(".toggleable").toggle();
```

Now it would look as though the texts changed, while actually you are hiding one element and displaying another.

Comment: I think this is the neater approach. In the original code there is a lot of html/content embedded in the code, so anyone reading the .html would be unable to see what is going on. This approach means the javascript is just the action.

Comment: I agree with @Quango - keep content and behavior separate. Other alternatives would be to use a class and some CSS so show/hide elements (and simply use `.toggleClass()`), or store the hide/show strings in `data-*` attributes so they're in the HTML and not the JS.

Answer (score 3):

Another option (though I have to say that I like @ZeroOne's solution in this case):

```
var getToggleHandler = function (opts) {
  return function () {
    var $this = $j(this);
    $j('.playlist-bar-tray')[opts.method]();
    $this.attr("title", opts.title);
    $this.children("div").html(opts.title);
    $this.children("span").html(opts.spanContent);
  };
}

$j('#hideShowBtn').toggle(getToggleHandler({
  method: 'slideUp',
  title: 'Show Playlist',
  spanContent: '&#9660;'
}), getToggleHandler({
  method: 'slideDown',
  title: 'Hide Playlist',
  spanContent: '&#9650;'
}));
```